# Different Colors for Different heights in spline chart in highchart

Tags: jquery, highcharts, background-color

I have an spline chart in highchart. its height is zero to one. I want to have all the points above the line y=0.5 have a red background color and points bellow this line have a green bckground. How can I do this in highchart?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#points").each(function(){
          if((this).val()>0.5)
              (this).css("background-color","red");
  });
})
```

Considered that your all points must have the id "points" and their values must be their respective heights(0.1,0.2,....like that)

Comment: I only set the "series" attribute in "plotOptions" in highchart. I want to know is there any option in highchart for this?

Answer (score 0):

"This feature is planned for Highcharts 3.0. We wrote up a temporary hack, which is limited to SVG browsers. That means that it won’t work in IE6, 7 and 8. See http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/PMyHQ/"
- @orstein Hønsi (Admin, Highcharts JS) - Nov 14, 2011

Source: http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general/suggestions/787281-threshold-option-for-colors

Answer (score 0):

You can very well create a utility method that converts your [`series.data`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.data) from `[[x,y],...]` into `[{ x:xVal,y:yVal,color:color,...}...]`

This function could look something like this

```
function groupDataByValue(data, threshold, aboveColor, belowColor) {
    var newData = [];
    $.each(data, function() {
        var dataPoint = {
            x: this[0],
            y: this[1],
            marker: {}
        };
        var color;
        if (dataPoint.y > threshold) {
            color = aboveColor;
        } else {
            color = belowColor;
        }
        dataPoint.color = color;
        dataPoint.marker.fillColor = color;
        newData.push(dataPoint);
    });
    return newData;
}
```

Before setting the `series.data` property pass it to this method and set the result value as the `series.data`

[Coloring points based on values @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/DzUfw/)